# Variable color not changing based on Value

Tags: jquery, css, json, html, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to assign color to `HTML` variable based on value. The value is getting picked fine from `JSON` but the color is not changing.

Here is the script to call the variable and assign the value:

```
<script>
  var xmlcurrgct = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var urlcurrgct = "../json/currgct.json";
  xmlcurrgct.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlcurrgct.readyState == 4 && xmlcurrgct.status == 200) {
      console.log("xmlcurrgct.responseText", xmlcurrgct.responseText);
      var obj1 = JSON.parse(xmlcurrgct.responseText);
      console.log("obj1", obj1);
      document.getElementById("currgct").innerHTML = obj1.text.currgct;
    }
  }
  xmlcurrgct.open("GET", urlcurrgct, true);


  var color;
  switch (currgct) {
    case "UP":
      color = "yellow";
      break;
    case "DOWN":
      color = "red";
      break;
  };
  xmlcurrgct.send();;
</script>
```

I am not sure what I am missing.The variable can have 2 values **UP** or **DOWN**.

**JSON:**
`{"text":{"currgct":"UP"}}`

Can someone help me in finding where I am going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't `switch` case contain like this -> `switch(obj1.text.currgct)`?

Comment: If i use switch(obj1.text.currgct) it says that obj1 is not defined .

Comment: Can you show the code where you use the value of the `color` variable?

Comment: <td><center><span id="currgct"></span></td>

Comment: I am sending the variable and ideally it should be able to get the color code from script and use it in same pattern in HTML.

Comment: That's because you have declared `obj1` inside `if`. Try keeping it outside `if` like `var obj1=""` and then assign inside `if` like `obj1 = JSON.parse(xmlcurrgct.responseText);`. I think that will do..

Comment: Now it is unable to  read  currgct . Cannot read property 'currgct' of undefined

Comment: I still don't see where you do anything with `color`. It's just a variable that is not referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var xmlcurrgct = new XMLHttpRequest();
var urlcurrgct = "../json/currgct.json";
xmlcurrgct.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlcurrgct.readyState == 4 && xmlcurrgct.status == 200) {
        console.log("xmlcurrgct.responseText", xmlcurrgct.responseText);
        var obj1 = JSON.parse(xmlcurrgct.responseText);
        console.log("obj1", obj1);
        document.getElementById("currgct").innerHTML = obj1.text.currgct;

        // You need to wait for the asynchronous response.
        var color;
        switch (obj1.text.currgct) {
            case "UP":
                color = "yellow";
                break;
            case "DOWN":
                color = "red";
                break;
        };

        document.getElementById("currgct").setAttribute("style", "color: " + color + ";");
    }
}
xmlcurrgct.open("GET", urlcurrgct, true);
xmlcurrgct.send();
```

Comment: This would work fine like before but do I need to call color in HTML while calling the variable ? I am calling  currgct in table and the color should reflect there .

Comment: You can assign a color like this: document.getElementById("currgct").setAttribute("style", "color: " + color + ";");

Comment: Thank you :) .. Just one small question .. The below code should work right if the JSON is returining a number .

Comment: switch (obj17.text.currfond) {
    case 0 ... 90:
     color = "green";
     break;
    case 91 ... 100:
     color = "red";
     break;
    };
   document.getElementById("currfond").setAttribute("style", "color: " + color + ";");
   }
   }

Comment: Yes, but you need to ensure that verifies a range of numbers. Check this example: 
 http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/fb5dvpr7/